# Find all matrices which commute with a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I wonder how to find all matrices $B$ which satisfy $AB=BA$, where

$A=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1&{}&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  1&1&{}&{}&{} \\ 
  1&1&1&{}&{} \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &{} \\ 
  1&1&1&1&1 
\end{array}} \right)$

(the coefficients above the diagonal of the matrix $A$ are zero). I tried Jordan form of $A$, but still couldn't see what to do next...

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A - I$ is nilpotent with rank $n-1$.  As such, $A$ is [non-derogatory](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Non-derogatory_matrix) (in particular, $A$ is similar to the Jordan block of size $n$ with eigenvalue $1$).  It follows that $B$ commutes with $A$ if and only if $B = p(A)$ for some polynomial $p$ (see Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* for a reference on this).

The end result is that $B$ will commute with $A$ if and only if $B$ is lower-triangular and [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).